# Logstash grok patterns testing

Tags: testing, logstash-grok, grok

I have 3 grok patterns that I want to test on a single log file. How do I make sure that all my log lines are being matched?

I already tried https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match, which seems to only allow me to try one pattern at a time.

If there is some kind of setting that shows me percentage of matches in logstash that would be great.

or if someone know how I can use the grokcontructor website with multiple patterns against one log file.

Answer (score 1):

I hope those three patterns can't be tested on a single log file. Hence please construct a common grok pattern for that single log file.

Please check out this example which has been done on grokconstructor website

[image: grok_multiline]